# Power consumption problem

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, powertop, tlp

Always when I return from suspend and check with powertop my consumption is about 16W.

If I put the recharge and take It out the consumption goes to 8W.

I am using kubuntu 17.10 with tlp and powertop.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: What CPU? `grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo`. In your tlp config do you have `SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1` and `SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=0`? If yes, try without it, or always 0.

Comment: grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz

Comment: About the SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT and ON_AC I have changed as proposed and nothing has changed

Comment: O.K. i thought your issue might be related to [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=121051), but I guess not.